# Animating an algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make an animation for an algorithm in JavaScript. More general though, how are algorithm animations done in other languages (i.e. Java)? Is the animation aspect separate from the algorithm logic? So, for example, I have my sorting algorithm working, and I would have a special Animation object that just "observes" the state of the list in question for any changes, or are the snippets in the algorithm logic that notifies the animation object of modifications to the list, and invokes the necessary animation methods?

Back to JavaScript, in may case, I have implemented an Huffman encoding algorithm that works; the only thing I'm trying to do is make an accompanying animation to demonstrate what its actually doing. So far, my approach is to use the [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) library or jquery for the animations, the only thing I'm stuck on is how to actually invoke any animation routines from my algorithm code.

I realize that its not really possible in JavaScript to pause execution at a line of code (or wait) for an animation to complete.

Any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

**EDIT:**
For example, the below code builds a queue of elements, and I would like to animate the queue being built as its doing it:

```
var i,j;
var input = $('#input').val();
var input_array = input.split('');
for (i=0; i<input_array.length; i++){
    var temp = new Node(input_array[i], 1);
    for (j=i+1; j<input_array.length; j++) {
        if (input_array[j] == input_array[i]) {
            temp.frequency++;
            input_array.splice(j, 1);
         }
     }
     Queue.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: What animation are you trying to do? Gots any html/css/javascript? Lets see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: For example, I would like to animate this snipped of code taht builds a queue. http://jsfiddle.net/ZNrFh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not possible to pause execution at a line of code or wait for an animation to complete.

Yes, that's true, since animations in JS are asynchronous. You have 2 choices:

- Make your algorithm asynchronous as well. This would be a function that gets the current state of the algorithm and returns the state after one step (and/or possibly the step itself so the matching single animation can be chosen). The step function would then be called from the animation loop each time.
- Maintain an animation queue (I guess your libraries have helper functions for that). Then run your algorithm as it is, and in each step chain another animation-to-be-executed at the end of the queue. Once the algorithm is ran, start the animation queue.

Option #1 is more elegant, but of course more complicated - all loops will need to become recursive functions etc. Yet this is the only possibility if your algorithm is non-terminating, or the animation queue of option #2 would become too long (and memory-eating).

Comment: I'm going to try the animation queue, to see how it works out, since it seems to require the least amount of alteration to the logic/flow of the algorithm, and I think it would serve as best in separating the algorithm logic from the animating presentation. Like you said, however, memory may be an issue, even though the queue is consumed as it expands. Perhaps a hybrid approach? For example, since Huffman has multiple stages. Possibly make those general operations atomic in order to pause execution at each of these major steps so the animation queue can recover to a more reasonable length.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure a hybrid approach is possible. However, I don't think memory really becomes a problem for any reasonable example.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate an animation in Javascript, you could modify inline style properties over time.

For example, to make a div element move to the right linearly, you might do something like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById("some-div");

//This would normally be done elsewhere
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.width = "100px;"
div.style.height = "100px;"
div.style.left = "0px";

//Called every 30 milliseconds
function animate() {
    div.style.left = (parseInt(div.style.left,10) + 5) + "px";
    setTimeout(function() {
       animate();
    }, 30);
}
animate();
```

However, I'd advise you look into using CSS3 [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions) or [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations), as it separates the site logic from the presentation and uses much less code.

Comment: If you look at the modified question, however, how would I match up my animation with the code that executes? The code in question would execute in 2 seconds, however, I would like to illustrate the execution via an animation.

Comment: @Eugen If `CSS3` is an option, you could use the `transition-delay` property, and animate an element just by changing the necessary property. For example, an element that starts with a `top` property of `10px` with a transition defined would smoothly animate to `50px` if `el.style.top` was simply set. Unfortunately, I don't entirely understand how you plan to accomplish animating elements with your example code above. I suggest you look at the links posted.

Comment: I apologize my problem/question is not as clear as I had hoped. Basically, in the example given, I loop through an array, and create a  Node object for each element. Looking at just that logic, I would like to illustrate this process by drawing a circle on the screen, with the element information inside that circle. The last line, pushes the Node object into a queue. Likewise, I would animate the previously created circle in a way to represent it as belonging to a queue. 

The drawings would be made in svg since it would be easier to handle animations and such.

I hope that is clearer.

Comment: What i'm not sure how to do is: How can I synchronize an animation with the logic of the data structure and processes as the routine executes. Since the routine finishes executing in a mater of milliseconds, yet the animation needs to finish executing in a matter of minutes (for example). This is, I think, my underlying question - How should I approach this?

Comment: @Eugen Perhaps you could invoke each event for each node with a calculated `setTimeout` delay, something like `var delay = Queue.length * 2000; setTimeout(function(){animate(node[i])}, delay);`

Answer (score 1):

now this is a really wide question to answer but i will try to cover some aspects of it ..

id like to start with the creation of animation ..

normally you would be manipulating the css of some element in order for it to look like it's an animation .. 
i would be playing with firebug and increasing the width of a div element and if i keep holding the up arrow it will look like its expanding .. further more , complex animations involve more aspects ..
JQuery library provide you with some really cool animations out of the box , and there are more advanced ones to see here is a simple fade-out animation if im not going to use jquery fadeOut() function

```
var op = 1; // set opacity to one 

setInterval(function(){
  op = op - 0.1 // decrease the opacity by 0.1
  $('div').css({opacity : op  }); // selecting the element an apply the css on it 
},50) // over an interval of 50 ms
```

now about stopping an animation or pausing it , nothing is impossible ...
with the previous animation 
here is an example ..
http://jsfiddle.net/9SaKL/1/

further more cool stuff can be done .. but this is just a lame example (don't apply it to real life project lol)

note that there is no use of re-inviting the wheel tons of animations can be done with just the basic ones used and combined together

```
I realize that its not really possible in JavaScript to pause execution at a line of code (or wait) for an animation to complete.
```

totally wrong , chaining is basically wating for one function to finish and then doing the other ...
clearing an interval is stopping ..

in real life if there is time and there is some thing that can be done on time then you can speed it or make it slower or you can stop it , (except time huh?)